# I hope we don't make the same mistake as we've already made. - I'd like to know if I can use "same as" like this

Tags: sentence-construction

Our company is scheduled to release the new product soon. But the release of the new product has been delayed because of some technical issues. In this situation, can I say like this?

> I hope we don't make the same mistake as we've already made.

***as we've already made*** is kind of redundant, but I'd like to know it is grammatically right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! "Same + noun + as" as a comparative is very normal. Note that you don't actually need to include "as" in this case. You can contract to just say

> The same mistake we've already made.

If I could just propose a simplified version that you may prefer:

> I hope we don't make the same mistake again.